# How to associate a custom field (primary contact) back to its correct title and email address?

Tags: administration

We have the SF Enterprise version and I am looking for some guidance. I created 2 lookup fields in the Opportunity called "primary contact" and "secondary contact". These contacts exist in the Contacts along with their titles and email, etc.  When I go to run a report, how do I get this primary contact's email address and title to come across in my report? I hope this makes sense as I'm trying to explain my issue here! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lookup fields, you should be using Opportunity [Contact Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contactroles_add_cex.htm&type=0&language=en_US). This would allow you to run standard Opportunity and Contact Roles reports to get the opportunity, account, and contact information, including their title, email, phone, addresses, and more. I *strongly* advise using this feature.

However, should you choose to proceed with your current design, you can either add formula fields to the opportunity, or you could create a [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=0) and include the extra fields you want via lookup relationships.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my question. I appreciate the help and will look into the Contact Roles!